# How do you remove the border of a Flex 4 TextArea Component (spark themed halo)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, adobe, halo

With the Flex 3 SDK you simply needed to set the borderThickness style to 0, or set borderStyle to none. With the Flex 4 SDK ad the Spark theme, this has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the borderSkin to null

```
<mx:TextArea borderSkin={null} />
```

Comment: The question is about spark.components.TextArea, not mx.controls.TextArea

Answer (score 9):

Try something like:

```
borderVisible="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the border from **spark** TextArea's here are some ways to do so:
To make all spark TextAreas have no border you can do this:

```
s|TextArea {
  borderVisible : false;
}
```

You can also make a simple style and only apply them to specific spark TextAreas like so:

```
.noBorder {
  borderVisible : false;
}
...
<s:TextArea styleName="noBorder"/>
```

You can turn it off via creation complete like so:

```
<s:Application ...
  creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"/>
...
private function onCreationComplete() : void {
  mySparkTextArea.setStyle('borderVisible', false);
}
...
<s:TextArea id="mySparkTextArea"/>
</s:Application>
```

Finally, you can make a skin, per DrMaxmAd's suggestion, like so:

```
...
<!-- border/fill --> 
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="#5C5C5C" weight="1" alpha="0"/>            
    </s:stroke>
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#FFFFFF"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't dabbled in Flash Builder 4 yet, but I know in Flex 3 you can modify things like this (when its not possible another way):

```
var tb:TextInput = new TextInput();
tb.getChildAt(0).setStyle(...);
```

Might want to give this a try, you just need to find the correct child element usually.

**EDIT**: [Here's your answer](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-21550)

Answer (score 0):

Jeol your answer works for MX components, for the flex 4 spark textarea component  you set borderVisible="false" and in code lblMessage.setStyle("contentBackgroundAlpha", 0);

Also, if your doing this, you probably want the hack to make the damn thing autosize to it's content... set heightInLines="{NaN}"

```
<s:TextArea borderVisible="false" focusEnabled="false" width="100%" id="lblMessage" heightInLines="{NaN}"  editable="false" selectable="true" lineBreak="toFit" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" />

protected function OnCreationComplete(objEvent:Event):void{
   lblMessage.setStyle("contentBackgroundAlpha", 0);
 }
```

...and Thanks for RobotLegs, it's freaking awesome!

Answer (score 0):

well i have tried the above code but it does not work for me Flex Hero SDK 4.5, so what i did i selected the textArea and created a new custom skin and change the border alpha to 0.

```
<!-- border/fill --> 
    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#5C5C5C" weight="1" alpha="0"/>            
        </s:stroke>
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
```

simple and sweet

Answer (score 0):

In Flex 3: The border for TextArea component can be controlled by using these two attributes/properties:

- borderSkin="{null}"
- focusAlpha="0"

Focus alpha ensures that you don't get the border showing up even when the TextArea is selected.