# Flex 4.5 - Remove border and border shadow for TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, flex4.5

How do you remove the border and border shadow in a Flex 4.5 spark TextArea? - setting  borderVisible="false", I still get a weird rounded rect border shadow. How do you suppress borders for all states (including edit, hover, etc)...

Also, how do you make that rounded rect into a sharp corners rect?

(This is related to an older question, but that's deprecated in [FB Burrito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045209/how-do-you-remove-the-border-of-a-flex-4-textarea-component-spark-themed-halo))